# how to add guest to google calendar link

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api

I am adding a google calendar link to my website as below

```
 <a href="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?
    action=TEMPLATE&
    text={{ticket.subject}}&
    dates=20170127T210000Z/20170127T220000Z&
    details=For+details,+link+here:+https://www.example.com/&
    location=Hyderabad,+Telangana,+India&sf=true&
    output=xml#eventpage_6" 
    target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Add to calender</a>
```

With the above Url, I can set the event title, event timing, event location

But now I want to add guest email like(dany@gmail.com) to the calendar event in the above link, was that possible?

Comment: Here you can find a comprehensive guide for google calendar properties: https://github.com/InteractionDesignFoundation/add-event-to-calendar-docs/blob/master/services/google.md

Answer (score 0):

```
Example: add=dany%40gmail.com
Format:  add=guest email addresses
```

Full list of parameters is available here: [Google Calendar render action Template parameter documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22757908/google-calendar-render-action-template-parameter-documentation)