# Google calendar add multiple event from site

Tags: google-calendar-api

On my site (asp .net mvc) users create many specific schedule for the day, week. May be up to 10-50-100 events on week. I want allow users import to own google calendar all events with one click.

I found  this [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488831/link-to-add-to-google-calendar).

But I need add many events with one click.

I need add many events with one click. If add 10 events in loop - user must 10 click to start add (go to url) and 10 click to save event in gCalendar.
I have google console account, i can generate file for import, i can write on JS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Link to add to google calendar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488831/link-to-add-to-google-calendar)

Comment: In link - add ONE event. I need add many avent with one click. If add 10 events in loop - user must 10 click to start add (go to url) and 10 click to save event in gCalendar.

Comment: I'm in the same situation. Did you ever find a solution to this? Thanks.