# Run code calendar google in localhost but not working in online server

Tags: php, calendar

I got it to work using a service account and some steps based on this answer, here is what I did: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50656151/adding-an-event-to-google-calendar-using-php)

This is work in local host.

i move all code to server , but not working online server.

Is it true to copy composer file without change?

Thanks.

Comment: Well then you need to go and start with some debugging, to find out what prevents it from working on the server.

Comment: Your question should address what exactly you did. Link that have been mentioned is their approach.

Comment: that is error $calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList();

Answer (score 0):

this problem was, php version host.