# How to add links in google calendar through API

Tags: google-calendar-api

I need to add hyperlinks either through summary or through description in API. 
For example, I tried it for summary, I added `<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>`, it came as text and not as HTML format, whereas in description, it came as HTML format but i couldn't hyperlink in it but just edit it.

I saw another solution in stackoverflow but that solution was not feasible because it redirects to another page before we get the actual site ([Link to add to google calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488831/link-to-add-to-google-calendar))

Can you please say some possible ways to add a hyperlink in Google Calendar?

Answer (score 1):

You have same scenario from this [StackExchage post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/27715/insert-hyperlink-in-google-calendars-description-field).

You can try this solution:

> Yes you can, by using the HTML code `<a href="http://www.google.com/">link</a>`. I have a Google calendar set
>   up for a club, if you are in edit mode, it appears as text, if you are
>   not in edit mode , ie log out of your Google mail, than look at your
>   calendar, the link will work. I hope this helps.

Comment: actually as i said, i've tried that, but when i edit, it appears as plain text. and another thing is that i cant access my google calendar when i log out google account, right?