# Link To Add Event to Office 365 Calendar

Tags: calendar, office365

Looking for an updated reference to add events to a readers Office 365 calendar.

[Found this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846807.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#single) but that is for live.com and not Office 365.

Have read the [Office 365 rest api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/calendar-rest-operations#CreateEvents) but that wouldn't work because we won't have access tokens to each users account.

The below answer is what am login for but just the Office 365 version. [Link to add to Google calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488831/link-to-add-to-google-calendar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a GitHub repository "add-event-to-calendar-docs" with a description of GET params for outlook web (and probably for Office 365 Calendar): https://github.com/InteractionDesignFoundation/add-event-to-calendar-docs/blob/master/services/outlook-web.md

Here is an example of a link:

```
https://outlook.live.com/owa/?path=/calendar/action/compose
    &rru=addevent
    &startdt=20201231T193000
    &enddt=20201231T223000
    &subject=Bithday
    &body=With%20clowns%20and%20stuff
    &location=North%20Pole
```