# Add a link to email to allow users add events created on website to their calendar

Tags: php, laravel, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I am trying to add a feature to my website that allows users to add an event created on the website to their calendar. 
Basically the app allows users to schedule a meeting and after which the meeting is sent to the mail of members of the site. What I want to do is to add a link with the meeting details to the site so users can click on it to add the event to their calendar, majorly **google and office 365 calendars**.

I have tried initially with **google calendar apis** but I can't seem to figure out what to do with the apis given. I was going to try with schema (with reference from google calendar api) to allow users to execute click actions but I realized it wont allow me to add events to the calendar but could be used to trigger certain actions which is not what I need at the moment.

I am building the app with laravel and can send the markdown email alright just need to be able to allow users a click action to add events to their calendar.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lance, the action taken when an ics file is clicked upon depends on the users application and their personal setup.  For example on my desktop I have it set that a .ics file will be opened in notepad++, whereas my iphone will have a more standard response. Then in Google for example it will automatically show events in google calendar that it has found in my gmail emails.

Other than sending the .ics in email, Some other things you can do:

- offer a 'Add to Google Calendar' button with html link.  More info here: [Link to add to Google calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488831/link-to-add-to-google-calendar).  This prompts add to default calendar.

Example:

http://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE&text=Friday%20Drinks&dates=20200501T080000Z/20200501T090000Z&location=407%20King%20St,%20Newtown%202042&trp=false&details=Regular%20Friday%20Night%20Get%20together%20at%20Earls%20Juke%20Joint

OR

- offer a subscribable link on the website, unique to each user,  of all meetings arranged.  Once they have subscribed they will automatically see new ones.  These would show in a separate calendar though.

I'm not aware of an Outlook 365 equivalent of the google 'TEMPLATE' - possibly they just go with the single event .ics.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ics files, which are supported on most platforms.

A sample PHP Library is https://gist.github.com/jakebellacera/635416

Comment: That was a very good resource but it it opens system calendar when the file is clicked. How do I trigger adding events to calendars like google calendar or office365 as mostly its not installed.