# Pre-Populate Google Calendar Subscribe by URL

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I want to pre-populate the URL box at

https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/settings/addbyurl

with my calendar feel link webcal://domain.co.uk/calendar/export.php?Staff=Mr+Alan+Smith

is there any functionality to create a subscribe link so users don't have to manually copy and paste the URL in ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Link to add to Google calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488831/link-to-add-to-google-calendar)

Comment: No @PatrickdC as these are all individual events, what I'm looking for is like the O365 system where you can pre-populate the URL for a calendar subscription... Like so... 
`https://outlook.office.com/calendar/addcalendar?name=NAME&url=webcal://domain.co.uk/calendar/export.php?Staff=Mr+Alan+Smith`

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer

`https://www.google.com/calendar/render?cid=webcal://domain.co.uk/calendar/export...`

doesn't like spaces so I also swapped spaces for _ in the url where I had spaces (%20 or +) in staff names e.g.

`webcal://domain.co.uk/calendar/export.php?Staff=Mr+Alan+Smith`
or
`webcal://domain.co.uk/calendar/export.php?Staff=Mr Alan Smith`
becomes
`webcal://domain.co.uk/calendar/export.php?Staff=Mr_Alan_Smith`

in my export.php which creates the ICS files it fetches, I then did a `str_replace()` to swap back the value to spaces.

`$staff = $_GET['Staff']; $staff = str_replace("_"," ",$staff);`