# Getting Google's own new event dialog to appear

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-calendar-api

I am making a Chrome extension to work with Google Calendar and I wonder if it possible to instigate Google's own new event dialog (as per the image below) programmatically in JavaScript using the calendar API? If I could set what date was displayed too, that would be even better.

[image]

After lots of experimentation, I found that I can go to a URL like this:

```
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/eventedit?dates=20230329T220000Z/20230329T220000Z
```

and this will be the "more options" version of the dialog in the picture - you can modify the start/end date in the URL and the dialog will change accordingly. I'd still prefer the simpler dialog.

...and more details in [this old SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488831/link-to-add-to-google-calendar) but still no info about getting the simpler dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are writing an extension, and you can read what the user sees, one way to trigger the popup is:

- Go to the monthly calendar view.
- Find the basic grid (in my case, identified by id=YPCqFe)
- Do some calculation to find the proper cell to click (they use attribute "data-datekey").
- Fire a click event on it.

Basic example with hardcoded values, try it in your own console after replacing "YPCqFE":

`document.getElementById("YPCqFe").children[0].children[1].children[0].children[1].children[4].children[0].click()`

Comment: Not a bad thought and I will investigate that approach some more - however my Chrome extension mainly concerns the "schedule" view which could make things trickier.