# Link to add and save event in google calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm trying to make a link that adds an event in my Google Calendar. Following an earlier entry ([Link to add to google calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488831/link-to-add-to-google-calendar)) I've been able to it, but it takes me to a page where I have to press the "Save" button to end the process. Is it possible to add a parameter to add the event without having to press the "Save" button?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here you can find a comprehensive guide for google calendar properties: https://github.com/InteractionDesignFoundation/add-event-to-calendar-docs/blob/master/services/google.md

Answer (score 4):

You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831877/how-do-i-create-a-link-to-add-an-entry-to-a-calendar/5832839#5832839). Try to add these parameters in your link:

- action=TEMPLATE (required)
- text (url encoded name of the event)
- dates (ISO date format, startdate/enddate - must have both start and end time - the button generator will let you leave the endtime blank, but you must have one or it won't work.)
- to use the user's timezone: 20131208T160000/20131208T180000
- to use global time, convert to UTC, then use 20131208T160000Z/20131208T180000Z
- all day events, you can use 20131208/20131209 - note that the button generator gets it wrong. You must use the following date as the end date for a one day all day event, or +1 day to whatever you want the end date to be.
- details (url encoded event description/details)
- location (url encoded location of the event - make sure it's an address google maps can read easily)